# Как отменить внутренние отступы при медиа запросе

Tags: html, css

Не получается убрать отступы у input, с другими тегами запрос работает

```css
.page9 {
  min-height: 469px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
.page9 .page9-logo {
  padding-top: 109px;
}
.page9 .page9-logo > img {
  max-width: 94px;
  max-height: 85px;
}
.page9 .page9-title {
  padding-bottom: 39px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}
.page9 .page9-form {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}
.page9 .page9-form > input[type=text] {
  border: 1px solid #d3d7d9;
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 69px;
  padding: 28px 228px 24px 28px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.page9 .page9-form > input[type=submit] {
  max-width: 126px;
  max-height: 69px;
  padding: 26px 45px 26px 45px;
}

@media (max-width: 220px) {
  .page9 .page9-title > p {
    word-break: break-all;
  }
  .page9 .page9-form > input {
    padding: 5px;
    word-break: break-all;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="page9">
      <div class="page9-logo">
         <img src="img/sheet9logo.png">
      </div>
      <div class="page9-title">
         <p>Stay on the saddle!</p>
      </div>
      <form action="#" method="GET" class="page9-form">
         <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="enter your email..." class="inputtext">
         <input type="submit" name="go" value="GO">
      </form>
   </div>
```

Пробовал давать отдельно каждому класс или обращаться по отдельности input[type="text"] (и input[type="submit"]), результат совсем никакой, отступы не уменьшает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Специфичность селектора инпута выше у кода над медиазапросом. Медиазапрос не повышает "силу перебивания" свойств, это нужно делать самостоятельно:

```css
.page9 {
  min-height: 469px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
.page9 .page9-logo {
  padding-top: 109px;
}
.page9 .page9-logo > img {
  max-width: 94px;
  max-height: 85px;
}
.page9 .page9-title {
  padding-bottom: 39px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}
.page9 .page9-form {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}
.page9 .page9-form > input[type=text] {
  border: 1px solid #d3d7d9;
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 69px;
  padding: 28px 228px 24px 28px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.page9 .page9-form > input[type=submit] {
  max-width: 126px;
  max-height: 69px;
  padding: 26px 45px 26px 45px;
}

@media (max-width: 220px) {
  .page9 .page9-title > p {
    word-break: break-all;
  }
  .page9 .page9-form > input[type=text] { /* <-- тут изменение */
    padding: 5px;
    word-break: break-all;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="page9">
      <div class="page9-logo">
         <img src="img/sheet9logo.png">
      </div>
      <div class="page9-title">
         <p>Stay on the saddle!</p>
      </div>
      <form action="#" method="GET" class="page9-form">
         <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="enter your email..." class="inputtext">
         <input type="submit" name="go" value="GO">
      </form>
   </div>
```

Если нужно и для кнопки, то можно писать например `input[type]` или как-то иначе усилить при сохранении универсальности.

Comment: Спасибо, сработало!